# Uniqueness of AKLT Ground State vs. SU(2) symmetry and Lieb-Schultz-Mattis theorem

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-entanglement, topological-phase, spin-chains, tensor-network

I have a question in my mind regarding the uniqueness of AKLT ground state. Currently I am watching a [video clip of MPS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_IBEAzqm4U&t=1448s) and I am curious why the AKLT ground state model is unique gapped ground state. The AKLT model is a spin chain where at each site there are two virtual spin particles. The maximal entangled bond $| \omega \rangle = |01\rangle- |10\rangle$ is rotationally invariant under $SU(2)$ group.  Therefore, AKLT state is also $SU(2)$ spin rotationally invariant. If we impose a periodic boundary condition into AKLT model, it becomes translational invariant. My question is that by theorem 1 of this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.11176), a spin chain with translational invariance and half-odd-integer spin rotation symmetry cannot have a unique gapped ground state. It seems that AKLT state satisfy these two conditions but the AKLT ground state is gapped unique. This contradicts with the LSM theorem and this implies I misunderstand the LSM theorem or the AKLT model. Could anyone point out my mistakes that I made  in my argument? I appreciate for any comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Lieb-Schultz-Mattis (LSM) theorem states that for a rotationally invariant (SO(3) invariant) 1D spin chain, such as the Heisenberg chain, with ***half-integer spin***, the system cannot be gapped with a unique ground state. In essence, this works by assuming a symmetric ground state (which it would be for a gapped system with a unique ground state) and subsequently constructing another state with an energy O(1/N) (IIRC).

The AKLT chain is a spin-1 chain. (Only the *virtual bonds* used to construct it are half-integer -- the *physical degrees of freedom* are integer spins.) That is, it is an ***integer spin chain***, and thus, the LSM theorem does not apply. On the contrary, what Haldane showed is that Heisenberg chains with integer spin will have a unique ground state and a gap above. Haldane's argument is not fully rigorous (at least from a mathematical physics point of view), and the AKLT model provides an example for a system which is close to the spin-1 Heisenberg chain and which, in particular, has the same underlying symmetries, and where the unique ground state + gap above can be proved in full mathematical rigor.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment and your great talk on MPS. I misunderstand the physical spin and the virtual spin particle in the construction of MPS. Besides, may I ask that is it possible to use the same method to construct the MPS of 1D Heisenberg spin chain using virtual spin particles? If Heisenberg spin chain is already spin-1/2, it seems that we have no way to construct the ground state in this way since we cannot further spilt spin-1/2 particles.